# Type I ANOVA tests not depending on the order of the factors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, experiment-design, unbalanced-classes, sums-of-squares

I have a dataset with two factors `A` and `B` and the following design (contingency table showing the number of individuals for each crossed level):

```
> xtabs(~A+B, data=dd2)
    B
A    B1 B2 B3 B4
  A1  8  8  8  8
  A2  7  7  7  7
  A3  8  8  8  8
  A4  4  4  4  4
  A5  4  4  4  4
```

I have observed that the Type I (sequential) ANOVA sum of squares do not depend on the order of `A` and `B` in the model. I was firstly surprised because the design is unbalanced and I have always believed that balanced design is the general condition required in order to have this property. Here the design is only balanced per each level of factor `A`. So finally what is the general condition under which the Type I sum of squares do not depend on the order of the factors ?

Comment: I would interpret this as balanced per each level of factor `B`. Or am I misunderstanding something? (+1)

Comment: At level A1 there are 8 values for each level of factor B: using only the data at level A1, the one-way ANOVA with factor B is balanced. Then I would say the design is balanced per each level of factor A, but maybe this is only a matter of language.

Comment: Makes total sense now. btw, Do you only find the effect with the main effect design `A+B` or do you run `A*B` and *don't* find any difference for type 1 tests?

Comment: With or without interaction there's no difference caused by the order.

Comment: Your design is an _unbalanced proportional_ design: the two main effects are independent (indeed, chi^2 of your table = 0) but their interaction term is not independent of them. With such design SS type I is the same no matter A or B is specified as first or second term. However sequence `A A*B B` or `A*B A B` will change results.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you. Can we take the nullity of the chi² as a characterization of this type of design ?

Comment: Yes. And with balanced design, of course, it is 0, too.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Your design is an *unbalanced proportional design*: the two main effects are independent (indeed, chi^2 of your table = 0) but their interaction term is not independent of them. With such design SS type I is the same no matter `A` or `B` is specified as first or second term. However sequence `A A*B B` or `A*B A B` will change results. – ttnphns

Can we take the nullity of the chi² as a characterization of this type of design ? – Stéphane Laurent

Yes. And with balanced design, of course, it is 0, too. – ttnphns